# Supremum & Infimum

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-empty sets and $h\colon X\times Y\to \mathbb R$ have bounded range in $\mathbb R$. Let $f\colon X\to\mathbb R$ and $g\colon Y\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x):= \sup\{\,h(x,y) : y\in Y\,\}$ and $g(x):= \inf\{\,h(x,y) : x\in X\,\}$.
Prove that $$\sup\{\,g(y) : y\in Y\} \le \inf\{\,f(x) : x\in X\,\}.$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, pick $y_0\in Y$ with $g(y_0)>g(y)-\epsilon$ for all $y\in Y$ and $x_0\in X$ with $f(x_0)<f(x)+\epsilon$ for all $x\in X$. Then $$\sup\{\,g(y):y\in Y\,\}-\epsilon\le g(y_0)\le h(x_0,y_0)\le f(x_0)\le \inf\{\,f(x):x\in X\,\}+\epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, the claim follows.